# JQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery function in a C# Razor view:

```
function calculateTotal(cost, freight, tax) {
   var costNum = cost.toString();
   costNum = costNum.replace(/,/g, '');
   costNum = parseFloat(costNum);

   var freightNum = freight.toString(); 
   freightNum = freightNum.replace(/,/g, '');
   freightNum = parseFloat(freightNum);

   var taxNum = tax.toString();
   taxNum = taxNum.replace(/,/g, '');
   taxNum = parseFloat(taxNum);

   var total = 0;
   total = costNum + freightNum + taxNum;

   total = numberWithCommas(total);

   return total;
}
```

and calling it from multiple places as such:

```
var MonthlyGrandTotal = calculateTotal(totalMonthCost, totalMonthFreight, totalMonthTax);
```

When I load the page in the browser I see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" in the console window.  It doesn't seem to be really affecting anything, but I'm curious as to why i'm seeing the error.

Comment: Why don't you check `totalMonthCost, totalMonthFreight, totalMonthTax` if defined?

Comment: Seems like totalMonthCost, totalMonthFreight or totalMonthTax are undefined and you are calling .toString() on them. The issue has to be further back in your code, since your function looks ok...

Comment: @AagamJain if you're going to do that, then just `var costNum = (cost || 0).toString();` is much more succinct.

Comment: @AagamJain, that did it.  So that just checks to see if cost is null and if it is not, sets it to 0.  Works great, thank you!

Comment: @AagamJain, if you add this as an answer I'll accept it :)